# Mysql пересечение касание

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица поездок курьеров из Москвы в уездный город N.

[image: таблица]
Скрипт добавления курьера в БД

```
function addSchedule($post) {   
        extract($post);
        $null = null;

        $stmt = DataBase::getDb()->msqli->prepare
        ("INSERT INTO `schedule` 
        (`id`, `region`, `courier`, `date_from`, `date_to`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('bssss', $null, $region, $courier, $date_from, $date_to);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo 'Добавлено в расписание';
        } else {
            echo 'Ошибка БД';
        }
    }
```

По задумке должно быть невозможно добавить определенного курьера, который уже находится в поездке. То есть должна быть функция, проверяющая этот момент и возвращающая тру фолс, в зависимости от которого будет работать или не работать функция вставки. Как ее реализовать?

```
function employmentCheck($post) {
        extract($post);

        $date_from = strtotime($date_from);//дата отправки с формы
        $date_to   = strtotime($date_to);//дата прибытия в регион
        $courier // сам курьер

        if ($query_user = mysqli_query(DataBase::getDb()->msqli, 
        "SELECT date_from, date_to  FROM schedule 
        //тут должно быть какое то условие, которое заставляет функцию вернуть фолс если эти значения даты уже есть в базе у данного курьера
        {

        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_user, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: `курьер требуемый and date_from <= $date_to and date_to >= $date_from` даст записи если есть пересечение дат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(id) AS count_id
FROM schedule
WHERE courier = "Генов Геннадий Геннадиевич" AND 
      date_from <= $date_to AND 
      date_to >= $date_from
```

Теперь проверяете переменную count_id и если она более нуля - значит курьер занят.

Но есть 2 момента:

1. Не нужно делать extract($post) - это очень небезопасно ([документация по extract()](http://php.net/extract)) - "**Внимание Не используйте extract() на непроверенных данных, таких как пользовательский ввод (например, $_GET, $_FILES).**"! Лучше вставлять данные как-то так: $post['region'],  $post['courier'] ...
2. В базе нужно создать доп. таблицу с именами (лучше для фамилии имени и отчества отдельные ячейки) и идентификаторами курьеров, а в таблице shedule вместо ФИО курьеров хранить их идентификаторы - этим вы заметно ускорите запрос по поиску незанятого курьера.

Comment: А почему бы для конкретной задачи не хранить курьеров и регионы (до кучи) в одной таблице но типом ENUM?

Comment: Потому, что тогда добавление нового курьера и региона будет требовать правок в структуре БД.